# Trying to route from login to home page using 'Navigator' but got error

Tags: react-native, navigator

[image]
[image]

2nd screenshot contains the code which I tried. Below is the whole code which I tried.

Code for index.android.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Navigator
} from 'react-native';
import Login from './Components/Login';
import Home from './Components/Home';

class Routing extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        initialRoute = {{
          id: 'Login'
        }}
        renderScene={
          this.navigatorRenderScene
        }
      />
    );
  }
  navigatorRenderScene(route, navigator) {
    _navigator = navigator;
    switch(route.id) {
      case 'Login':
      return(<Login navigator={navigator}
      title="Login" />);
      case 'Home':
      return(<Home navigator={navigator}
      title="Home" />);
    }
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => Routing);
```

Code for Login.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  Image,
  View,
  Button,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  Linking,
  Alert
} from 'react-native';

export default class LoginPage extends Component {
  _onSubmit() {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      id:'Home'
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.containerView}>
        <Text style={styles.loginText}>
          Username or Email
        </Text>
        <TextInput style={styles.inputFields}
          placeholder="e.g: abc@example.com" />
        <Text style={styles.loginText}>
          Password
        </Text>
        <TextInput style={styles.inputFields}
          placeholder="Password"
          secureTextEntry={true} />
        <Text style={{color: 'blue', marginBottom: 10}}
          onPress={() => Linking.openURL('https://www.google.co.in')}>
          Forgot Password?
        </Text>
        <Button
            onPress={this._onSubmit.bind(this)}
            title="Login"
            style={styles.loginButton}
            accessibilityLabel="Ok, Great!"
          />
      </View>
    );
  }
};

const styles= StyleSheet.create({
  containerView: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ffebcd',
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderColor: '#000000'
  },
  loginText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    marginBottom: 10
  },
  inputFields: {
    fontSize: 20,
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderColor: '#000000',
    borderRadius: 30,
    marginBottom: 10
  },
  loginButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#34A853'
  }
});
```

Code for Home.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native Hello World!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.android.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,{'\n'}
          Shake or press menu button for dev menu
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

module.exports = 'Home';
```

Comment: @AdamPatterson I have uploaded my whole code here. Please check and suggest what can be done.

Comment: @Kirti, I made a few edits to my answer. Good luck. Also, make sure you thoroughly try to solve the problem before asking for solutions. I was surprised to find you were importing a component that doesn't exist. Be more specific about what you have tried, when the problem started, etc

Comment: @AdamPatterson Thanks for reply. I did the changes and on click of login button I'm getting error: "Expected a component class, got [object Object]. Please suggest where I'm doing mistake.

Comment: @Kirti, Is the initial problem solved? Does this error give you a line number?

Comment: @AdamPatterson Yes sir, initial problem solved. This error is not giving me any line number

Comment: @Kirti, Are all of your classes capitalized? At the bottom, get rid of `module.exports = 'Home';`

Comment: @AdamPatterson Thank you so much. It worked for me. Sir can you please provide me some explanation why this module.exports is not required? And what are the things I was doing wrong? It would help me in future as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138803/discussion-between-kirti-and-adam-patterson).

Comment: @kirti, a statement like: `import myDefault from 'my-module';` Means that you are importing a **default**, so you must export a default as well. Which is why you needed `export default class Home extends Component {` instead of `module.exports = 'Home';`. These docs cover this topic: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
 `class Home extends Component {` needs to be exported as well:

```
export default class Home extends Component {
```

This is because you are using **named exports**, docs here:
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

 Furthermore:

```
export default class LoginPage extends Component {
```

Should be:

```
export default class Login extends Component {
```

When you name things, they need to be consistent.

-------------------------------
The error you are getting is likely because:

```
class Routing extends Component {
```

Should be:

```
export default class Routing extends Component {
```

The line `_navigator = navigator;` does nothing.

 
If you want to make the function private you should do:

```
    export default class Routing extends Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
      }
      _navigatorRenderScene(route, navigator) {
       Do stuff...
      }

  render(){
    return(
      Do stuff...
    );
  }
}
```

I moved the function above of the render method because it is easier to read, and it is conventional.